# Speeding up date pattern matching

Tags: java, date, design-patterns

I am writing some simple code that tries to deduce whether or not a specific String is actually a Java date and, if yes, identify its format (pattern).

Obviously, because there are many possible date formats, establishing which one is applicable for a string requires successive pattern matching, which is really time and CPU-consuming, given that the input string can have other values, too.

So, what I have ended up doing, for a String variable called `input`, is something like

```
String datePattern;

if (isLikeDate(input))
{
    datePattern = matchAnyOfThePredefinedDatePatterns(input);
}
```

where the `isLike...` method rejects obvious non-date strings and the `match...` method goes over about 40-50 predefined patterns, trying to construct a valid SimpleDateFormat object. The constructor throws an exception if the `input` string is not a valid date for the pattern examined each time.

The exception handling slows things down dramatically, but there seems to be no avoiding it. The Apache Commons Date packages exhibit similar performance.

Is there any faster way of implementing this date pattern matching?

Comment: This is just off the cuff, but did you consider tracking down the SimpleDateFormat.java source (perhaps in Harmony or Harvest -- I forget the name) and changing it such that it fails nicely?  Nicely being: does not throw an exception.

Comment: @DwB Probably not a bad approach.

Comment: I have done that, but unless I replicate the code it is not doable. I am trying to use the standard library without such hacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the complexity of the patterns, you might want to match each potential pattern with a regex (or hand-written code) before *trying* to parse it properly as a date. For example, if the pattern is "yyyyMMddThh:mm:ss" you could check for the length, the position of the T, the position of the colons, and that everything else is a digit before passing it on to the date parsing code.

This level of pattern matching can be very liberal - it's only trying to rule out *definite* infringements of the pattern. The important thing is that it doesn't reject any values which are actually *valid*.

The downside is that for any pattern which *does* match, you're doing work twice - but that may well still be easily balanced by significantly reducing the number of exceptions you throw.

EDIT: Just to clarify, you're currently testing whether it looks like it could match *any* of the patterns, and then testing *all* of them. I'm suggesting that you have a regex for *each* pattern, and only try parsing against patterns which have already matched the corresponding regex.

I'd also suggest trying [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) - not only is it a generally better API, but its patterns are thread-safe, so you can reuse them. Presumably you're currently creating new `SimpleDateFormat` objects each time you have something to parse.

Comment: Agreed, this is what the isLike... method does.

Comment: I think a regex-based approach would be just as slow; checking absolute positions would be the most likely speedup, but I'd wonder if it's worth it.

Comment: @Dave: It depends on the regex implementation quality but I think it would at least be worth testing. As ever, performance should be tested :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Now if there was just an automated way to test the ROI of implementing and testing alternatives...

Comment: @PNS: See my edit. Only try parsing against patterns which have a good chance of working.

Comment: A regex-based approach would perhaps be faster, but SimpleDateFormat does not expose the regex it generates from its patters. As for the position-based checking, not sure how this could be done. A date pattern is an abbreviated representation of a variable-length date string, so how could positions be matched?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider building a trie-like state machine, sort of like playing pachinko with the incoming string. This would fail relatively quickly on non-dates–basically a date grammar parser.

Not sure if it would *always* be faster, or faster-enough to be worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

> match... method goes over about 40-50 predefined patterns, trying to
>   construct a valid SimpleDateFormat object.

Does this mean you are constructing new `SimpleDateFormat` objects in every call to `match`? That is quite expensive, don't do that.

Keep the format objects previously constructed. If I remember right `SimpleDateFormat.parse()` is not thread-safe so some extra work will be required.

Of course, you want to try the formats with higher chances of succeeding first, but I don't know if you have that insight into data patterns.

Comment: A similar thing to do would be to have a HashMap<String, SimpleDateFormat>, where String would be the pattern and SimpleDateFormat the corresponding object. If this is accessed by a single thread but every SimpleDateFormat object is used to parse many input strings, it should be OK.

Comment: I assume there is a threadpool? I would just put the `HashMap` in a `ThreadLocal`.

Comment: You mean, if it the HashMap is a static variable in a class which is used by different threads in the same pool, it should be protected, even if it is only read (not written)?

Comment: It is not about the **construction** of `SimpleDateFormat`. If two threads call `parse()` on the same `SimpleDateFormat` then all sorts of strange things can happen.